# why so many line data can't get?

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

My code:

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
equitydown="http://sc.hkex.com.hk/gb/www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm"   
file=urllib.urlopen(equitydown).read()   
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file) 
rdata = root.xpath('//tr[@class="tr_normal" and (.//img)]')
for data in rdata:
    data.getparent().remove(data)
for code in root.xpath('//tr[@class="tr_normal"]/td[position()=1]'):
    print code
```

you can see the output ,(omitted many)

```
00320
00321
00322
00323
00325
00326
00327
00328
```

but when you open [Hong Kong Exchanges and Clearing Limited](http://sc.hkex.com.hk/gb/www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm) you get many lines, such as  (omitted many):

```
06830 华众控股 2,000 #  
06838 盈利时 2,000 #  
06868 天福 1,000 #    
06880 豪特保健 2,000 #   
06883 新濠博亚娱乐 300 #
```

I lose many codes: 06830 06838  06868  06880 06883  (omitted many), which the code is behind 00329, all of  them  lost.

I  don't get  all  the code,why?

---

```
import urllib
import lxml.html
equitydown="http://sc.hkex.com.hk/gb/www.hkex.com.hk/chi/market/sec_tradinfo/stockcode/eisdeqty_c.htm"   
file=urllib.urlopen(equitydown).read()   
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file) 
for code in root.xpath('//tr[@class="tr_normal" and not(.//img)]/td[position()=1]'):
    print code.text_content()
```

it still get  wrong  output,please make a try  to run it to see what happens?
the code behind 00328 can't get,what's the reason?

Comment: Are you sure that the ones not showing in your output to have the class `tr_normal` ?

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested yet? What was the outcome?

Answer (score 2):

Triage notes:

Saved a copy of url content to a file in case it's a moving target.

Threw it at the [W3C HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) ... result was:

> Sorry, I am unable to validate this document because on line 18 it
>   contained one or more bytes that I cannot interpret as gb2312 (in
>   other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified
>   Character Encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the
>   character encoding indication.
>
> The error was: euc-cn "\xFA" does not map to Unicode

Aside: There are lies, damned lies, and encoding declarations that allege `iso-8859-1` or `gb2312`.

Attempted `content.decode('gb2312'`, it failed.

```
 >>> guff = open('lxml_hke_raw.htm', 'rb').read()
 >>> len(guff) 715608
 >>> guff.decode('gb2312') Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> UnicodeDecodeError: 'gb2312' codec can't
 decode bytes in position 171039-171040: illegal multibyte sequence
 >>> pos=171039
 >>> guff[pos:pos+2]
 '\xfa\xe2'
```

Exploration around the failure position yielded the following (manually indented, many irrelevant attributes removed or abbreviated):

```
<tr class="tr_normal">
    <td class="verd_black12" width="18%">00329</td>
    <td class="verd_black12" width="42%">
        <a 
            href="http://sc.hkex.com.hk/etc/etc/etc"
            target="_parent"
        >
            <img
                src="http://sc.hkex.com.hk:80/fs?FAE2+5+13+004B96"
                alt="\xfa\xe2"  #### not a valid gb2312 sequence ####
            > #### also the "img" element is not terminated ####
        \xc1\xfa\xb9\xfa\xbc\xca
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="verd_black12" width="19%">10,000</td>
    <td class="verd_black12" width="3%" align="center">#</td>
    <td class="verd_black12" width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="verd_black12" width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="verd_black12" width="3%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

That indicates why it stopped at the element containing `00329`. Note there's another case of this much later in the file.

Kludge:

```
ucontent = content.decode('gb2312', 'replace')
repchar = u'\uFFFD'
print ucontent.count(repchar) # 2
ucontent2 = ucontent.replace(repchar, '[NON-GB2312 SEQUENCE]')
content2 = ucontent2.encode('gb2312')
```

This can be written to a new file, or parsed:

```
root = lxml.html.document_fromstring(content2) 
for el in root.iter('tr'):
    if el.get('class') != 'tr_normal': continue
    print all(ch.tag == 'td' for ch in el), [ch.text for ch in el]
```

Abbreviated output:

```
True ['00001', None, '1,000', '#', 'H', 'O', 'F']
True ['00002', None, '500', '#', 'H', 'O', 'F']
...
True ['00328', None, '2,000', '#', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0']
True ['00329', None, '10,000', '#', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0']
True ['00330', None, '100', '#', 'H', 'O', 'F']
...
True ['06880', None, '2,000', '#', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0']
True ['06883', None, '300', '#', u'\xa0', u'\xa0', u'\xa0']
```

One other puzzle:

The original content is decoded OK by Python 2.7.2 with `gb18030`. However changing the charset in the file didn't work (no output after `00329`). Also attempts to override the encoding using lxml's `encoding` arg had the same effect.

Observation: The offending `\xfa\xe2` is decoded by `gb18030` to `u'\ue331'` which is in the BMP [Private Use Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Private_use_characters), which accounts for the `img` element which provides a url for a GIF that will display the intended character.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `00329` is the first one with an `img`, so I figure your `remove` is the problem. Maybe it messes up the xpath iterator, try converting it to a `list` first.

Or try:

```
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file)
for code in root.xpath('//tr[@class="tr_normal" and not(.//img)]/td[position()=1]'):
  print code
```